# Blogger API v3 : when calling /posts/search/, parameter nextPageToken is not working

Tags: blogger, blogger-dynamic-views, google-blogger-api

When calling {URL}/posts/?{parameters} :

the 10 first items are returned
if the response contains more than 10 items, an attribute { "nextPageToken":"xyz" } is added to the JSON data response.
Then when calling {URL}/posts/?{parameters}&pageToken={nextPageToken} :

the response contains the next 10 items
a new nextPageToken is returned until no more page
=> Looks like the expected behavior, working fine.

However:
When calling {URL}/posts/search/?q={query_string}{parameters} :

the 10 first items are returned
if the response contains more than 10 items, an attribute { "nextPageToken":"xyz" } is added to the JSON data response.
Then when calling
{URL}/posts/search/?q={query_string}{parameters}&pageToken={nextPageToken} :

- the 10 first items are displayed again (ie not the next 10),
- returned nextPageToken is the same than first call

Looks like pageToken is ignored for /posts/search/.
Is this the expected behavior? How to access items of /posts/search/ response returning more than 10 items?

Replicated issue.

[https://blogger.googleapis.com/v3/blogs/{blog](https://blogger.googleapis.com/v3/blogs/%7Bblog) id}/posts/search?q={search}&key={api key}&pageToken={next page tok}&maxResults=100

Comment: Hi @bolt-uix, I also have this issue in my app, did you solve it ?

Comment: I did not find a solution, so I am loading max=500 records & doing filter/search by app side.

Comment: Can you update your question with this solution, please because the `maxResults` parameter is not working with me on search also